# Is there a built-in function for iteratively processing the result of freemarker strings?

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a use case where I want to recursively process the result of freemarker processing.

So if I have a Map var with the following data

```
var = {"a" : "${b}", "b" : "Value I want"}
```

and my input string is

```
"Input string is ${a}"
```

If I process this once using Template.process(var, stringWriter), I get the result

```
"Input string is ${b}"
```

I need to process this again to get

```
"Input string is Value I want"
```

What I am looking for is a built-in function like Template.process(var, stringWriter) which does processing iteratively on the result. Does such a function exist?

I can process recursively myself but I am looking out if such functionality already exists.

Note : I am posting my first question so please don't mind if I missed some norm

Comment: Eval and/or parse can be used; I don’t think there’s anything else built-in to handle recurring template strings.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such functionality in the FreeMarker API.

Looks like you will need a data-model where they keys are `a`, `b`, etc., and the values will be `TemplateScalarModel`-s, where `getAsString` lazily creates (via `new Template`) and processes a template, using the same data-model, and then stores its result for later reuse. You will also need a shared set of variable names that are under processing, to detect circular dependencies.